# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors"

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am using `fields.hasErrors` in the following code but I am getting an error:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: 
>   "#fields.hasErrors('${parametrosFormulario[0].valor}')}" "

I have a `th:object="${parametrosFormulario}"` and I am using it in the following line:

```
<div class="labelselect flota_izquierda col60" 
     th:each="parametro , stat:      ${parametrosFormulario}" 
     th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('${parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor}')}? 'labelselect_error'" >
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong. An answer would be appreciated!

Comment: i think you did mistake in selector ${parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor}

thymeleaf using pojo object with getter setter method ${#fields.hasErrors('objectname')}

Comment: ${parametrosFormulario} is an object list with "valor" field. So by doing "${parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor}"  i am passing  for example in first iteration ${parametrosFormulario[0].valor} which i think is right. I dont know why it is still giving an error. even if i do 'parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor' it still doesn't work

Comment: Show your controller code for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

## fields.hasErrors expect the bean's field argument to be pass.

```
<div class="labelselect flota_izquierda col60" th:each="parametro , stat: ${parametrosFormulario}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('parametrosFormulario['+__${stat.index}__+'].valor')}? 'labelselect_error'" >
```

Comment: Thanks. But it shows like "The field parametrosFormulario[0].valor could not be empty"
I am using the following code after above line:
<label class="flota_izquierda label_formulario col33" th:utext="__${parametro.descricion}__+':'"></label>    
<input type="text" class="flota_centro" th:name="parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor" th:id="parametrosFormulario[__${stat.index}__].valor"
     th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('parametrosFormulario['+__${stat.index}__+'].valor')}? 'label_error'" th:value="${parametro.valor}" />

I want to print the descricion value (label of empty field )